# Finding Radius of Convergence for Power Series

Tags: calculus

Find the radius of convergence of the given power series:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{ \infty} \frac{8n!x^n}{2^n}$$

After taking the limits as n-> $\infty$, I get $\frac{8x}{2}$, and Radius of convergence is R = 2. Is this correct?

Comment: This is a very standard, very straightforward problem; what have you tried?

Comment: Use the Ratio Test. Informally, the problem is that $n!$ grows hugely fast.

Comment: Try by using the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Ratio Test, it looks like we get $R=0$.

$$\left|a_{n+1}\over a_{n}\right| = \left| \frac{8(n+1)! \cdot x^{n+1} \cdot 2^n}{2^{n+1} \cdot 8n! \cdot x^n} \right| = \left| \frac{8(n+1)n! \cdot x \cdot x^n \cdot 2^n}{2\cdot 2^n \cdot 8n! \cdot x^n} \right|$$

$$=\frac{\left|x\right|} {2} \lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1) \to \infty \ \ \forall x \ne 0\implies R=0$$

Thus, the power series only converges when $x=c$, which is at $x=0$ here.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Finding_the_radius_of_convergence) can help you solve this problem.

The answer is:

> $0$